# iterate through unserialized wordpress options array in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to ultimately grab the wordpress plugin slug and new version values  from this object array. I've done a lot of research and tried many examples but none really show this array format. I am confused by the index structure. Help is appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the array structure from the unserialized wordpress data.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [last_checked] => 1594309667
    [response] => Array
        (
            [advanced-custom-fields/acf.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields
                    [slug] => advanced-custom-fields
                    [plugin] => advanced-custom-fields/acf.php
                    [new_version] => 5.8.12
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/advanced-custom-fields.5.8.12.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1082746
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1082746
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/banner-1544x500.jpg?rev=1729099
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=1729102
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [tested] => 5.4.2
                    [requires_php] => 5.4
                    [compatibility] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [amp/amp.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/amp
                    [slug] => amp
                    [plugin] => amp/amp.php
                    [new_version] => 1.5.5
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/amp.1.5.5.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/amp/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1987390
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/amp/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1987390
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/amp/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1987390
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/amp/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1987390
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [tested] => 5.4.2
                    [requires_php] => 5.6
                    [compatibility] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [edit-author-slug/edit-author-slug.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/edit-author-slug
                    [slug] => edit-author-slug
                    [plugin] => edit-author-slug/edit-author-slug.php
                    [new_version] => 1.7.0
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/edit-author-slug.1.7.0.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/edit-author-slug/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1582213
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/edit-author-slug/assets/icon.svg?rev=1582213
                            [svg] => https://ps.w.org/edit-author-slug/assets/icon.svg?rev=1582213
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/edit-author-slug/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1581739
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/edit-author-slug/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1582213
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [tested] => 5.4.2
                    [requires_php] => 5.6.20
                    [compatibility] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/essential_adons_elementor.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite
                    [slug] => essential-addons-for-elementor-lite
                    [plugin] => essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/essential_adons_elementor.php
                    [new_version] => 4.0.4
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite.4.0.4.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=2285897
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=2285897
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/assets/banner-1544x500.gif?rev=2317134
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/assets/banner-772x250.gif?rev=2317134
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [tested] => 5.4.2
                    [requires_php] => 5.4
                    [compatibility] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/gravity-forms-event-tracking.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking
                    [slug] => gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking
                    [plugin] => gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/gravity-forms-event-tracking.php
                    [new_version] => 2.3.10
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking.2.3.10.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1777199
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1777199
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1777199
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1777199
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [upgrade_notice] => <p>Prevent empty values to be sent to analytics when using partial entries.</p>
                    [tested] => 5.4.2
                    [requires_php] => 5.6
                    [compatibility] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                )
```

I try this but get error of both slug and new version being an undefined index.

```
foreach($plugins_us as $item) {
    echo $item['slug'];
    echo $item['new_version'];

    // to know what's in $item
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects from which you're attempting to get those values isn't an array but rather a generic object which is why you cannot access the value using its index. Try instead accessing them as attributes on the class:

```
echo $item->slug;
echo $item->new_version;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I try that and get an error saying I'm trying to get a property of a non-object

Comment: I assume you are iterating through the array that is the value of the 'response' key, correct? It looks like each item in that array is an object based on that assumption but there is no information in your question about what is assigned to $plugins_us variable. Perhaps calling gettype() on $item will help you determine what type it is and therefore how to access those attributes.